# encrypt to multiple public keys with RSA using Webcrypto

Tags: javascript, encryption, rsa, public-key

is there any way to encrypt data for multiple public key (so multiple key owner can decrypt data using their private key) using javascript cryto Api.

If that is not possible using RSA-OAEP, can you please suggest way for the same?

Thanks

```
window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
    {
        name: "RSA-OAEP",

    },
    ArrayOfPublicKeys, 
    data 
)
.then(function(encrypted){

    console.log(encrypted);
})
```

Comment: It is not mathematically possible, is it? You'd have to create a separate ciphertext for each public key.

Comment: thanks for commenting , but how other pgp programs support multiple user encryption?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/554513/pgp-encrypt-single-message-for-multiple-recipients

Comment: Not sure exactly how that works though.

Comment: @pointy, read the first comment of the post you linked _what PGP does is generate a key for a symmetric cipher, and cipher that for each recipient with their public key. So the message for many recipients isn't much larger than that for 1_

Comment: @pedrofb yes I read that but I can also phonetically read some Korean writing :)

Comment: @Pointy: Not only is it possible, it's common,

Comment: You probably want Enveloped Data from CMS.  It's apparently not part of WebCrypto, but other javascript libraries exist.

Comment: yes @bartonjs , but how can I do it with pure javascript without using library, or in other words , how do libraries like "openpgp" make the output for all users in one plaintext?

Comment: @pedrofb , this is also a solution , but not for my case , since they all have to get the same message, not one different message for every user.

Comment: CMS Enveloped Data: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5652#section-6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dr Jack Millan.

The way PGP, S/MIME and other similar messaging solutions enable a multi-party message is to:
1. Generate a Message Encryption Key (MEK), for example, an AES key for use with mode GCM,
2. Look up the public key of each recipient,
3. Encrypt the MEK to each recipient's public key,
4. Package the encrypted MEKs with the encrypted message,
5. Distribute to participants.

The challenge here is the secure discovery of public keys, most applications punt on this and make the user do manual thumbprint verification or rely on a third-party such as a Certificate Authority to verify the binding of a key to a subject.

You can find an example that does this using webcrypto with a single recipient here:
https://pkijs.org/examples/CMSEnvelopedExample.html

The source for this demo is here:
https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/PKI.js/tree/master/examples/HowToEncryptCMSviaCertificate

Comment: Thanks @rmshrisk
I just see that and it looks so complicated, the question is what if I can make my own style , the other one is which steps do I have to follow to achieve the standrad CMS?

Comment: You of course can, but there are pitfalls you can run into and as such I generally tell those unfamiliar to rely on tried and true formats. Another is: https://github.com/square/js-jose happy to help more if you provide an more example though.